# Render an element inside literal templates with a EventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert an element with an `EventListener` at a certain point of an element. I can achieve this via `appendChild` but I want to insert it at a certain point. Like this:

```js
const divT = () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const div_inside = document.createElement("div");
  div_inside.addEventListener("click", () => {console.log("div_inside")});
  div_inside.innerHTML = "INSIDE";
  div.innerHTML = ` TEST ${div_inside.outerHTML} TEST `;
  return div;
};
document.body.appendChild(divT());
```

The main problem is the `outerHTML` does not contain the information of the listener. There is a method to render the HTML with the listener still active?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you do this `div.innerHTML = \` TEST ${div_inside.outerHTML} TEST \`;` you're creating a new `div_inside` element, that has not event handler attached. Append `div_inside` to `div` similarly you've appended `div` to the body.

Comment: Yes, I know, only asking if there is a method to render with the listener attached to it or is mandatory to do it via `appendChild` or a similar method.

Comment: Yes, it's mandatory, `div_inside.outerHTML` is just a plain string, there's no way it could contain an event listener attached to a previously created element.

Comment: For example [`lit-html`](https://lit.dev/docs/v1/components/events/#add-declarative-event-listeners) allows you to render with the listener attached to it. I was wondering if there is a method to do it with the native tools.

Comment: Okey. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I need to build a method for doing it, no native approach.

Comment: The difference is, that in the lit example there's an "attribute", which can be processed to event in the method the string is passed. `addEventListener` doesn't add any attributes to the elements.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for yout time

Answer (score 0):

Find a workaround using [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) and attaching an empty div:

```js
const divT = () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const div_inside = document.createElement("div");
  div_inside.innerHTML = "Hello World";
  div_inside.addEventListener("click", () => {console.log("div_inside")});
  div.innerHTML = ` TEST <div id="inside"></div> TEST `;
  const div_s = div.getElementsByTagName('div')
  div_s[0].insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', div_inside)
  return div;
};
```